# How to schedule test without TFS

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, automated-tests

Here is my need:
I have several [TestMethod] A, B, C, D, E, F
And I have a test list may contain A, B and C. I use the mstest.exe to run the test list. I want to run the A first, and maybe 30 minutes later run B and then C. I don't use TFS now. Is there any way can implement this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Windows Task Scheduler](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721871.aspx)

The Task Scheduler is capable of handling many scenarios and is easy to script.

Comment: Windows Task Scheduler can schudule the mstest.exe but what I want is to schedule the test case in the test list.

Comment: Make test sets, and schedule each test set.